# Reading records from a file in FORTRAN66 using stdin adding extra unwanted junk

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to read a file in the format specified below using FORTRAN 66.

```
1000
MS 1 - Join Grps    Group Project       5             5             
Four Programs       Programming         15            9             
Quiz 1              Quizzes             10            7             
FORTRAN             Programming         25            18            
Quiz 2              Quizzes             10            9             
HW 1 - Looplang     Homework            20            15
```

I execute and read the file like so:

```
program < grades.txt
```

The first line is the total number of points that can be earned in a class
The rest of the lines are assignments in a class
Each line is formatted as such: Assignment name(20 chars) category (20 chars) possible points(14 chars) earned points(14 chars)

For some reason, when the code runs and reads the file, starting at the first assignment record, I get error 5006, and cannot find an explanation of the error code. The output of the program while debugging looks like this:

```
$ file < grades.txt
MS 1 - Join Grps    Group Project                    5       6417876
 NOT EOF
 EOF        5006
NAME               CATEGORY            POSSIBLE      EARNED
```

My goal is to be able to read each line and put each column into it's appropriate array, then reference those arrays later on to print a report for each category, with each assignment, points possible, earned, and total percentage for the category, then loop, etc.
I do not understand where the "6417876" in the output is coming from, it is definitely not part of the file that's being piped into stdin while the program reads.
The code for the program is as follows:

```
       CHARACTER*20 ASSIGNMENTT(100)
       CHARACTER*20 CATEGORY(100)
       INTEGER POSSIBLE(100)
       INTEGER EARNED(100)
       INTEGER TOTALPTS
       INTEGER REASON
       INTEGER I, N
       READ(5,50)TOTALPTS
50     FORMAT(I4)
c      Read the arrays in
       I=1
100    READ(5,110,IOSTAT=REASON)ASSIGNMENTT(I),CATEGORY(I),POSSIBLE(I),EARNED(I)
110    FORMAT(2A20x,2I14x)
       WRITE(*,110)ASSIGNMENTT(I),CATEGORY(I),POSSIBLE(I),EARNED(I)
       I=I+1
       IF (REASON < 0) GOTO 120
       WRITE(*,*)"NOT EOF"
       IF (I<100 .AND. REASON == 0) GOTO 100
       WRITE(*,*)"EOF", REASON
c      Get the number of items (For some reason stdin adds an extra item that's not in the file, so I subtract 2 instead of 1
120    N=I-2
c      Display the Names and Ages
       WRITE(*,200)
200    FORMAT("NAME",T20,"CATEGORY",T40,"POSSIBLE",T54,"EARNED",T68)
       DO 300 I=1,N
210    FORMAT(A20,A20,I14,I14)
300    WRITE(*,210)ASSIGNMENTT(I),CATEGORY(I),POSSIBLE(I),EARNED(I)
       END
```

What could be causing the read issues I'm facing?

Comment: Wow.  FORTRAN 66 vintage.  Your issue is likely whitespace and/or lack thereof.

Comment: That's what I assumed but I've counted the number of trailing white spaces and each field adds up to the correct total number of characters (including white spaces)

Comment: The program above is not Fortran 66. A quick visual grep puts it at least Fortran 90 (comparison operators, length of variable names, there may be other). Character is also Fortran 77.

Comment: Interesting find, thanks

Comment: The ultimate reason is the line with label 100 is too long, as quickly found through opening the file in my editor, and so being truncated. Split it into two lines - fix that (and the non-standard format 110) and I think the program is working. I'll let somebody else work out why this is the fix, probably related to some undeclared variable or other, I don't really feel motivated to debug archaic code like this.

Comment: Looks like that solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: I was actually unable to figure out how to split the line, nothing worked, so I ended up shortening the names of the longer arrays.

Comment: That was what my cryptic comments were trying to convey, but I stopped saying any more due to annoyance at people still teaching this rubbish

Answer (score 0):

The line to read the file contents was too long, so I shortened the names of the variables to save some space and the problem was solved.

Comment: Please don't shorten names for this. Look up continuation lines. Better learn Fortran which is less than half a century old - no new code should be being written in anything older than Fortran 2003 nowadays.

Comment: I havent been able to find a way to do it without the compiler failing. This is an assignment for a class so I really have no choice in what version of fortran I use. I have to do the same program in COBOL next.

Comment: This is a really poor answer to the question, I hope no-one follows this approach.

Comment: This is probably the only time I'll ever use the language so it's meh

Comment: At least tell your instructor that there have been 5 major revisions to the Fortran programming language.  The version s/he appears to be teaching is 40 years old.

Comment: Yea, he's fairly young, isnt teaching the language, just providing examples and having us work as a group to reproduce four specific programs in various languages, first the language of our choice, then fortran, then cobol, and so on in the future